# Como definir a formatação para uma tabela com várias colunas usando classes?

Tags: html

Eu fiz um site e dentro do corpo tem 6 colunas com links e cada coluna esta dentro de uma `class`, tipo assim:

```
class="coluna 1"
class="coluna 2"
class="coluna 3"
```

O que eu quero saber é se esta certo isso ou eu posso fazer de outra maneira.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não está errado, mas há outras maneiras de fazer de fazer isto. Por exemplo utilizando `nth-child` do CSS.

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0.5rem;
}
td {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

td:nth-child(1) { background: hsl(150, 50%, 50%); }
td:nth-child(2) { background: hsl(160, 60%, 50%); }
td:nth-child(3) { background: hsl(170, 70%, 50%); }
td:nth-child(4) { background: hsl(180, 80%, 50%); }
td:nth-child(5) { background: hsl(190, 90%, 50%); }
td:nth-child(6) { background: hsl(200, 99%, 50%); }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>This</td>
    <td>Little</td>
    <td>Piggy</td>
    <td>Went</td>
    <td>To</td> 
    <td>Market</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">This</td>
    <td>Little</td>
    <td>Piggy</td>
    <td>Went</td>
    <td>To</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="4">This</td>
    <td rowspan="3">Little</td>
    <td>Piggy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">This</td>
    <td>Little</td>
    <td>Piggy</td>
    <td>Went</td>
    <td>To</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Little</td>
    <td>Piggy</td>
    <td>Went</td>
    <td>To</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Fonte: http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/fixJg

Comment: Vlw cara, vou dar uma boa olhada nisso!